# Sublime Text 2 move cursor out of parenthesis, quotes, or brackets

Tags: sublimetext2

I need a fast way to make the cursor jump outside the auto wrap qoutes or other syntax elements.  I don't want to have to reach down to my arrow keys each time, and definitely don't want to go to my mouse.

[image]

Is there a quick and easy way to solve this for my workflow?

Comment: Just so you know, you can still type `"` from there and it will skip past the `"` without adding another one. Or, of course, you can set up a keybinding to jump ahead.

Comment: @BoundinCode LOL -it is so simple I could kick myself for never even trying to type through -problem solved.  The keybinding option might be useful too.  Thanks.

Comment: Just realized I can skip outside of the tags and start at the next line by hitting `Command Return`.  I should probably check the shortcuts listed here:[gist:1207002](https://gist.github.com/lucasfais/1207002) since there are so many cool features to Sublime.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use a shortcut (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, or whatever you like) to move the cursor.

In your `Key Bindings - User`:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} }
```

Comment: Is it possible to bypass multiple quote ?  like this one ["shift + space"], when cursor is after word space, I have to push shift+space twice.

Comment: @huangli yes but we need to write a plugin. then we can look at the character that caret stands on, and act upon that. that means we can even manipulate the tab to go out from quotes, and insert a tab when there is not quote.

Answer (score 16):

I made a few key bindings out of macros as well.

**You must make a macro for these,** unless you want to spend more time building them, but it's really easy.  Just go to Sublime Text, `Tools` > `Record Macro`, or hit `ctrl` `Q`.  Save the file in Packages/User/ and then hit `⌘` `,`  to open up your User Settings.  Paste the settings below in there and boom. **( The  | below represents my cursor )**

[image]

Here are the one's I chose:

---

### Function auto-bracketizer

When the cursour is here:

```
totallyAwesomeness(|)
```

Use the **option + tilda** shortcut.

### ⌥ ~

This prefills the function with brackets and the text ' # code... ' highlighted. It only works when inside the parenthesis.

#### Sublime User Settings

```
{
"keys": ["option+`"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/superBracketizeFunction.sublime-macro"}
},
```

[Download Macro](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5LhVy_zkvWqQ1NqaGlkY2dieUU/edit?usp=sharing)

---

### Auto-End Line With Semicolon

When the cursour is here:

```
echo 'say what!!??|'
```

Use the **command + semicolon** shortcut.

### ⌘ ;

This adds a closing ; at the end of current line and moves you to the line below it. It actually works wherever you are on the line.

#### Sublime User Settings

```
{
"keys": ["super+;"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file":  "Packages/User/superEndLineWiSemiColin.sublime-macro"}
},
```

[Download Macro](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5LhVy_zkvWqT3J2MW44V2ZBaUE/edit?usp=sharing)

---

### Exit Argument & Exit Function

When your cursor is anywhere inside the function it will end up here:

```
public function totallyAwesomeness()
    {
        echo 'say what!!??';
    } |
    echo 'yep... that just happened';
```

Use the **command + enter** shortcut.

### ⌘ Enter

This will let you jump outside the argument and a space to the right as well as anywhere from within the function it will jump you out of it just being the closing bracket.

#### Sublime User Settings

```
{
"keys": ["option+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/superExitFunctionArg.sublime-macro"}
},
```

[Download Macro](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5LhVy_zkvWqZ1U2R3NORXRUdXc/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Just in case you don't know what the path is to your User folder is, it is shown below.

```
/Users/alexcory/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/
```

Also the Library folder is usually hidden, so you can download a program called [Revealer](http://trcdatarecovery.com/software-apps/revealer-app) that will allow you to toggle those hidden files.

If you want to know how I made these just hit me up and I'll show you! :D

Comment: You should swap first and last 'Download Macro' links

Answer (score 9):

Best solution for this is **recording a macro** on Sublime Text and then assigning it to a keyboard shortcut. Follow these steps:

1. Create a line such as alert('hello') and leave the cursor right
   after letter 'o'.
2. Then go to *Tools > Record a Macro* to start recording.
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to go to the end of line.
4. Press <kbd>;</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Stop recording the macro by going to *Tools > Stop Recording Macro*
6. You can now test your macro by *Tools > Playback Macro* (optional)
7. Save your macro by going to *Tools > Save Macro* (ex: EndOfLine.sublime-macro)
8. Create a shortcut by adding this between the square brackets in your
   in your Preferences > Key Bindings - User file:

   ```
   {
   "keys": ["super+;"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/EndOfLine.sublime-macro"}
   }
   ```
9. Now, every time you hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, it will
   magically place the semicolon at the end of current line and move the cursor to the next line.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

A more complete way to make a key binding would be:

```
    { "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\"\\]]", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
        ]   
    },
```

Assuming you want  <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> as the shortcut. Or you can change it to  <kbd>tab</kbd> as well

As found in http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5174#p23086

Answer (score 3):

Following Riccardo Marotti's post;

If you would like to bypass the bracket on the next line, you can replace "characters" with "lines" in the args section.

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true} }
```

Answer (score 2):

on a Dell XPS, Ctrl Enter does the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

I just have this feature partially implemented with the help of *a plugin named run_multiple_commands.py* (see below)

(**only tested on ST3,** but the plugin is earlier than the first version of ST3 and should work on ST2 too).

Shortcut configuration is as below:

```
{
    "keys": ["shift+space"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} }
        ]
    },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "[)\\]}'\"]$", "match_all": true},
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},

{
    "keys": ["shift+space"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
        ]
    },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\\]}'\"]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},

{
    "keys": ["shift+space"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "brackets"} },
        ]
    },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[(\\[{]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},

{
    "keys": ["shift+space"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "brackets"} },
            {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
        ]
    },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\\]}'\"]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[)\\]}'\"]$", "match_all": true},
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "^[(\\[{]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

One shortcut (`shift+space`) for four conditions:

1. cursor is just after quotes or closing parentheses/bracket:

   move one character forward
2. cursor is just before quotes or closing parentheses/bracket:

   move one character forward
3. cursor is just before opening parentheses/bracket:

   move to closing parentheses/bracket
4. !`1` && !`2` && !`3`:

   move to closing parentheses/bracket

   and move one more character forward

To use this configuration in your ST, you should first add a file named `run_multiple_commands.py` to your `.../Package/User/` directory, and the content of which is the second code piece of  *[This Article](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8677)*

This solution is just fine for everyday use but is not perfect because:

1. the cursor is unable to jump out of quotes (just step over it when the cursor is directly followed by one).
2. the cursor is unable to jump out of the nearest parenthesis, quotes, or brackets when the code block is commented.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + M is the default one that I have on windows machine.
Just do it

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the <kbd>home</kbd> and the <kbd>end</kbd> key are near to your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to move cursor one space forward. Also, on mac, I interchanged <kbd>caps lock</kbd> with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. <kbd>caps lock</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> is much easier to reach. It works fairly well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way which lies within sublime keybindings itself. Basically, I just modify the keybindings for auto closing parens, that is, I replace `"contents": "($0)"` with `"contents": "($1)$0"`. Then just hit `Tab` to get out of the parenthesis. So I add in my keybindings the following:

```
{ "keys": ["("], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "($1)$0"}, "context":
    [
      { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|;|\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

And similar for square brackets, curly brackets, and single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ctrl + PgUp Cycle up through tabs

Ctrl + PgDn Cycle down through tabs
```

This can go to the end of brackets

Answer (score 0):

for example you are typing print("hello")

- so to move your cursor out you can press the double quotation mark (") once again.
- to move out of brackets also press the end or right bracket key again.