# Keyboard shortcut to show/hide tabs and status bar in ST3 OSX

Tags: sublimetext3

*How do I set up a keyboard shortcut to show/hide tabs and the status bar in Sublime Text 3?*

At the moment I have to go View->Show/Hide Tabs. I'm using OSX. I have for instance

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": 
{"by": "characters", "forward": true},
```

in my key bindings user file which I set up (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800608/sublime-text-2-move-cursor-out-of-parenthesis-quotes-or-brackets) answer!) to move the cursor one space forwards by pressing shift and space, and ideally I'm looking for something similar to show/hide tabs and the status bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the ST console, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Then execute the command through the menu as normal. The command being executed (with arguments if applicable) will be displayed in the ST console. You can use the information there to create a key binding to the appropriate command.

Comment: So there's a way to toggle tabs/statusbar, but is there a way to permanently hide them?