# In Brackets is there a key to easily advance past automatic sentinels?

Tags: javascript, editor

I put Brackets in the title, but this question applies to any of it's peers... VSCode, Sublime, Atom, etc.

When you type [, (, etc, these editors auto place the closing sentinel and put the cursor in between. Handy.

Typically, as far as I know, that's it. They help you get in but don't help you get out. So I wind up having to reach *all the way over* to the `End` key to get out. (oh the inconvenience.) And since that's outside of normal range I look down to do it, therefore it's ultimately as distracting as it is helpful... a wash.

Do any of these editors have a alternate key to advance the cursor past the sentinel? (Even tho something like alt-arrow is 2 strokes, it's within the mental space of the kb and can be done without looking or thinking abotu it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom Key bindings to move past the closing brackets. See some helpful [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800608/sublime-text-2-move-cursor-out-of-parenthesis-quotes-or-brackets). Additionally, If you just type the closing bracket it will skip past it. For example, if you type

`if(` the editor will automatically add `)`. if you just type `)` you will notice that you skip past it. This is true for Sublime Text 2 at least.